# Rotating a model in 3d in lua

Tags: lua

I have this ugly model of a dodecahedron that i need to rotate (live) on every axis:

```
local phi = 1.618
local b = 1 / phi
local c = 2 - phi
  self.polys = {
    {{ c,  0,  1},   {-c,  0,  1},   {-b,  b,  b},   { 0,  1,  c},   { b,  b,  b}},
    {{-c,  0,  1},   { c,  0,  1},   { b, -b,  b},   { 0, -1,  c},   {-b, -b,  b}},
    {{ c,  0, -1},   {-c,  0, -1},   {-b, -b, -b},   { 0, -1, -c},   { b, -b, -b}},
    {{-c,  0, -1},   { c,  0, -1},   { b,  b, -b},   { 0,  1, -c},   {-b,  b, -b}},
    {{ 0,  1, -c},   { 0,  1,  c},   { b,  b,  b},   { 1,  c,  0},   { b,  b, -b}},
    {{ 0,  1,  c},   { 0,  1, -c},   {-b,  b, -b},   {-1,  c,  0},   {-b,  b,  b}},
    {{ 0, -1, -c},   { 0, -1,  c},   {-b, -b,  b},   {-1, -c,  0},   {-b, -b, -b}},
    {{ 0, -1,  c},   { 0, -1, -c},   { b, -b, -b},   { 1, -c,  0},   { b, -b,  b}},
    {{ 1,  c,  0},   { 1, -c,  0},   { b, -b,  b},   { c,  0,  1},   { b,  b,  b}},
    {{ 1, -c,  0},   { 1,  c,  0},   { b,  b, -b},   { c,  0, -1},   { b, -b, -b}},
    {{-1,  c,  0},   {-1, -c,  0},   {-b, -b, -b},   {-c,  0, -1},   {-b,  b, -b}},
    {{-1, -c,  0},   {-1,  c,  0},   {-b,  b,  b},   {-c,  0,  1},   {-b, -b,  b}}
  }
```

The main problem that i have is that i have absolutely no idea what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a short question for a potentially long topic. I would suggest you start [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/programming-3d-shapes/a/rotating-3d-shapes) for an gentle introduction to the math behind 3D rotation.

If you are truly interested, I would look at the “3D ebook” link on [this](https://bitbucket.org/TwoLivesLeft/core/wiki/Home) site. The book is targeted towards users of *Codea*, a Lua programming environment on the iPad. The first major example that it leads up to is rotating a 3D cube. Please note that the code is not completely portable to other Lua environments, as it relies on some built-in Codea functions. That said, it is a very easy intro to 3D concepts in general, and as a plus, it uses Lua. And Codea is great, by the way.

If you are looking for someone to just code it up for you, this may not be the place. Better to learn the concepts, and come to SO when you get stuck.